# create site Collection from site template containing blog subsite sp2013

Tags: sharepoint, sitecollection

I want to create a site collection based on a `site template` that contains a `calendar app` and a `blog` subsite.

I explain, i have a site that contains a subsite of type `blog` site and also contains a calendar in `sharepoint 2013`, i saved the site as a template and checked **`include content`**.

However,
when i create a new sitecollection based on that template, i get the caledar app but never the blog subsite...

Am i missing something here? And how can we do this please?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you can try to export the blog as a template itself and create the subsite in the new site collection using the exported template